# Sentencia PL/SQL erronea

Tags: plsql

Estaba probando una combinacion de sentencias entre una funcion, y un procedimiento que llamaba a la misma, y no acabo de ver porque no funcionan.

La función se encarga de sacar el conjunto de duración de una tabla de película, y calcula la media de las mismas.

Esa media es la que le pasa al procedimiento como parámetro para que la muestre:`

Esta es la tabla a la que llama:

```
CREATE TABLE  PELICULA 
   (    CODIGO NUMBER(6) CONSTRAINT PELICULAS_PK PRIMARY KEY, 
    TITULO VARCHAR2(50), 
    GENERO VARCHAR2(20), 
    DURACION NUMBER(3), 
    FECHA_ESTRENO DATE,
        CODIGO_DIR NUMBER(6),
        CONSTRAINT DIRECTOR_FK FOREIGN KEY (CODIGO_DIR) REFERENCES DIRECTOR (CODIGO) ON DELETE SET NULL
   );
```

Y esta son las sentencias PL/SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PeliPorGenero(pGenero VARCHAR2)RETURN NUMBER
AS
CURSOR cur IS SELECT duracion FROM PELICULA WHERE genero=pGenero; 
media NUMBER;
vdur NUMBER;
cont NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
    FOR vpeli IN cur LOOP
        vdur:=vdur+(vpeli.duracion);
        cont :=cont+1;
    END LOOP;
    media:=vdur/cont;
    RETURN media;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE llamada_PeliPorGenero(pGen VARCHAR2)
AS
vdur pelicula.duracion%TYPE;
BEGIN
    vdur:= PeliPorGenero(pGen);
    IF (vdur IS NOT NULL)THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('La duración media de las peliculas de genero ' || pGen || ' es de ' || vdur);
    ELSE
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No existen peliculas con ese género');
    END IF;
END;

EXECUTE llamada_PeliPorGenero('DRAMA');
```

El problema esta en que la variable vdur en la función se carga con null, aunque no veo ningún error
a la hora de desarrollar la función.

Espero podaís echarme una mano, y ¡muchas gracias de ante mano!

Comment: Si corres el query con ese valor te trae resultados? Para descartar lo obvio, los datos una vez cargados en la tabla están comiteados no?

Comment: Sisi, si que retorna resultados, el problema viene porque dentro de la función al ejecutarse el valor que retorna es NULL, por lo que al llegar porocedimiento entra por el ELSE.

Answer (score 0):

En Oracle, tanto SQL como PL/SQL, cualquier operación con columnas y variables que tengan valor nulo (o NULL en inglés) produce como resultado un valor nulo, excepto en casos de algunas funciones específicas para manejo de nulo.
.
La siguiente sentencia siempre tendrá un resultado nulo:

```
 vdur:=vdur+(vpeli.duracion);
```

esto por cuanto el valor inicial de la variable "vdur" es nulo.

Hay 2 opciones:
a) Asignar en el momento de la declaración el valor "0" (cero).
b) o usar la función NVL como en

```
 vdur:=nvl(vdur,0)+(vpeli.duracion);
```

De paso hay una manera más sencilla de obtener el promedio

```
SELECT sum(duracion)/count(*) 
FROM PELICULA 
WHERE genero=pGenero;
```